# Django Database Model Sum

Tags: django, django-models

I have business logic to ranking user by closing rate (selling some item) this is my models

```
class Payments(models.Model):
    method = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Status(models.Model):
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class DataCustomer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(Payments, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    sales_name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

If sales selling something with payment method CASH with status Deal get point 13
and if with payment method CREDIT with status Deal get point 8

how can i impelement the query in views.py and in template tag?

Comment: How would you like to show that on template?@Fatur Ewing

Comment: Basically, you can use **pre_save** signal on you `DataCustomer` model to increase the points of `Sales` based on `payment_method` and `status`.

Comment: i got stuck on view and template when showing up the data for current user

Comment: Do you want to store the points of user as a **field** in your `Sales` model or just calculate it each time on the fly?

Comment: @PedramParsian better to store in database or no?

Comment: if store to database, how?

currently i just triggered for deal and payment status.

Comment: @FaturEwing It's better to store them on database if your system will have huge amount of `DataCustomer` objects (for better performance). Also check my answer on **how to do that**.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method on your DataCustomer model to give the points acording to the condition. Something like this:

```
class DataCustomer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(Payments, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    sales_name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def calculate_points(self):
        if self.payment_method__method == 'CASH' and self.status__status_name == 'Deal':
            return 13
        elif self.payment_method__method == 'CREDIT' and self.status__status_name == 'Deal':
            return 8
        return 0
```

Then is just call .calculate_points() on DataCustomer object on views or templates.

Comment: and how i show the current point with table, example. User1 Cash Point 26 Credit Point 8. Please help

Comment: Then you will have to link user table to DataCustomer table and put a method there to make the sum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the `points` of each `Sales` in the database, first you should have a **field** in you models:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    # other fields ...
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then, you need a trigger like `pre_save` for your `DataCustomer` model:

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import reveicer

@receiver(pre_save, sender=DataCustomer)
def data_customer_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.pk:  # checking whether the object is new or it's being updated
        sale = instance.sales_name
        if instance.status == Status.objects.get(status_name='Deal') and instance.payment_method == Payments.objects.get(method='CASH'):
            sale.points += 13
        if instance.status == Status.objects.get(status_name='Deal') and instance.payment_method == Payments.objects.get(method='CREDIT'):
            sale.points += 8
        sale.save()
```